# KendoUI DropDownListFor event binding - Error: "Does not contain definition for Events"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, dropdownlistfor, event-binding

I am currently working with KendoUI using ASP.Net MVC Razor syntax.

I have drop downlists and editor widgets that are working well.

Problem came up when I needed to bind an event to a JS function.

I followed the docs found here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/dropdownlist/events.html

In my partial view:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientType)
                              .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("FetchAllClientTypes", "ClientType")))
                              .DataTextField("Description")
                              .DataValueField("Id")
                              .AutoBind(true)
                              .ToClientTemplate()
                              .Events(e => e.Change("Test"))
                      )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientType)
```

But,on building, I get the error:

> Error 67  'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Events' and no extension method 'Events' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\WorkingForlder_Details.cshtml   193 32  NameSpace.ToApplication

NB: The data binding and everything else works. It is the Event Binding that's failing

Any idea why its failing to build?

Comment: remove .ToClientTemplate() and put at the end after .Events and try

Comment: Thanks Rudresh. That did it! Please make it an answer and I will mark it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove .ToClientTemplate() and put at the end after .Events and try